# How to validate all the column of a particular header name in excel using POI api

Tags: java, excel, validation, apache-poi

I have a excel with headers, empName, empId, Department. I need to provide dropdown for user to enter department Name. User should be able to entry only the values present in drop down. I tried below code but it is not validating department column.
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(2, 2, 2, 2);
        DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[] { "ACCOUNTS", "ISE", "SALES" });
        DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, dvConstraint);
        dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
        sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);

Answer (score 1):

Following code creates a workbook having a sheet having the header cells

```
  |    A    |   B   |     C      |
1 | empName | empId | Department |
```

in `A1:C1` and data validation list  in `C2:C65536` in `HSSF` or `C2:C1048576` in `XSSF`.

The code works for binary `*.xls` files (`HSSF`) as well as for `Office Open XML` `*.xlsx` files (`XSSF`).

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

class CreateExcelDataValidationListsWholeColumn {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  String[] headers = new String[]{"empName", "empId", "Department"};
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  for (int c = 0 ; c < headers.length; c++) {
   row.createCell(c).setCellValue(headers[c]);
  }

  //data validation in column B, except first row:
  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"ACCOUNTS", "ISE", "SALES"}) ;
  int lastRow = workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion().getLastRowIndex();
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, lastRow, 2, 2); // C2:C65536 in HSSF or C2:C1048576 in XSSF   
  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
  sheet.addValidationData(validation); // data validation for C2:C65536 in HSSF or C2:C1048576 in XSSF

  FileOutputStream out = null;
  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationListsWholeColumn.xls");
  } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationListsWholeColumn.xlsx");
  }
  workbook.write(out);
  workbook.close();
  out.close();

 }
}
```